# Weird networking issue with MBP WiFi (El Captain)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arp

Maybe somebody can help me with the following issue?

I've get recently the absolutely new MBP with El Captain installed on it. And it refuses to work with home WiFi. Every few minutes it disconnects from the network (to WiFi network itself it's connected) and when I perform `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping 10.100.102.1` (router) I get: `Request timeout for icmp_seq X`, where X from 0 to Infinity

From googling I've found solution which restoring network for a couple of minutes, clearing arp table by `sudo arp -ad`.

What did I try:

- to disconnect all other network devices from wifi - nothing
- replaced dhcp server range to another `192.168.1.1`,`192.168.1.5` - nothing
- replaced WiFi channel to another one nothing (in general there aren't many WiFi networks around me, maybe one or to)

What does work:

- Another MBA which run same El Captain works perfect
- Windows laptop, android, iPhone works perfect
- Same computer with other WiFi router works perfect
- Same computer with this router but connected by ethernet cable works perfect

There're arp tables when internet disconnected and after I've cleared it back, there's some difference but I don't know networking to evaluate it:

**When internet disconnected**:

```
anatoly-mac:etc anatoly$ sudo arp -a
? (192.168.1.1) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on en0 permanent [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.1) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.255) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
broadcasthost (255.255.255.255) at (incomplete) on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
anatoly-mac:etc anatoly$ sudo arp -ad
192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) deleted
192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) deleted
192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255) deleted
224.0.0.251 (224.0.0.251) deleted
255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255) deleted
```

**And after I've beed cleared it it looks so (internet works):**

```
anatoly-mac:etc anatolyt$ sudo arp -a
? (192.168.1.1) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on en0 permanent [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.1) at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

*P.S. For privacy reason I've hide my real mac address by `xx:xx:xx...`.*

Comment: Do you got at home babycam or some wireless device? I ask as I got at home a vtec babycam and they use a special wifi channel & encryption, and it scrambled my wifi. Anything near the receptor/parent unit lost the wifi or get bad ping.

Comment: Nothing special, Nexus 5 phone, another MBA. But I'll try to turn it off to test if they cause interference.

Comment: Is this by any chance related to subnetting and the fact that your router is using 10.100.x.y and your mbp something around 192.168.a.b? This setup MIGHT work, of your router and mbp do have the correct routes and at least the router needs an additional ipaddress within 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann, actually I tried to give various ip addresses to my router, the issue isn't gone. Every time when I changed IP address of the router my MBP was in the same subnet. Actually I don't think I can set router in one subnet while MBP in other subnet while I using router's DHCP.

Comment: Which router is it? Perhaps, the router and the WiFi chipset in the MBP are incompatible. I heard a similar story once.

Comment: It's ISP provided ADB VV 2220 https://www.adbglobal.com/vv-2220/

Comment: I'm ashamed but issue was solved by restart. There are a various reasons why do I love OSX, one of this is ability to work months without restarting and cycle sleep/work takes just few seconds, so I make restarts very occasionally, when I install update or installed software requires it. Now I began encounter slowness and when opening new iTerm tab was taking more then 15 seconds I decided to restart it. When it back, slowness has gone, network issue too. Thank you for your help gentlemen. Now I doubt, leave or delete this topic, what do you advice?